# How to display max. 2 sticky posts when posts_per_page is 3?

Tags: posts

I have problem with sticky posts. This is my loop:

```
<?php
$main_loop = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date',
);
$query = new WP_Query($main_loop);
?>
     <?php if ($query->have_posts()): ?>
     <?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();?>

// loop

     <?php endwhile;?>
     <?php wp_reset_query();?>
     <?php endif;?>
```

Now, when posts_per_page is 3, I need display max. 2 sticky posts. So:

when 1 sticky there's also 2 regular posts, when 2 sticky there's also 1 regular posts, when 0 sticky there's 3 regular posts.

How should I do it?

Comment: Just to be clear you want to avoid showing 3 sticky posts?

Comment: Yes, but not avoid showing sticky posts at all. I want show max only 2 sticky posts nad 1 regular. Max 3 posts.

Comment: What happens to the third sticky post if there are three? Don't show them as sticky, but in the "normal" loop?

Comment: Then third sticky should not show.

Comment: If there are three, then should show i think only two lasts sticky posts. Maybe there is other logical solution for this. Anyway I need show max. 3 posts and I want use sticky. Maybe it should be only one sticky, maybe that would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2: Updated Code to account for "Maybe there are no stickied posts" ;)

Edit: I did a boo-boo with the number of posts. Fixed, should work now as intended.

You can do this by using two queries.

```
<?php
//First, you get all the sticky posts
$stickies = get_option('sticky_posts',array());
//then, get max 2 of them
$stickiessliced =array_slice($stickies,0,2); 
$numposts = 3 - count($stickiessliced);
//$numposts is now the number of remaining "normal" posts to be queried
if(count($stickiessliced)){
    //only query the stickies if there are some
    $sticky_loop = array(
        'posts_per_page' => count($stickiessliced),
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post__in' => $stickiessliced,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    );
    //only get sliced sticky posts, ignore everything else
    $query = new WP_Query($sticky_loop);
    //do the loop for the sticky posts
    if ($query->have_posts()): ?>
         <?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();?>

    // loop

         <?php endwhile;?>
         <?php wp_reset_query();?>
    <?php endif;
}
//now get the remaining posts to fill up to three
$main_loop = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $numposts,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post__not_in' => $stickies,
    //replace $stickiessliced with $stickies to make sure that NO other stickies are queried (as is: the above queried stickies are ignored)
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
);
$query = new WP_Query($main_loop);
//do the loop for the remaining posts to fill up
if ($query->have_posts()): ?>
     <?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();?>

// loop

     <?php endwhile;?>
     <?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php endif;
?>
```

This should work like this: if there are 0 to 2 sticky posts, they are queried, looped and then 1 to 3 "normal" posts are queried. If there are more than 2 sticky posts, the first 2 are sliced and then 1 more "normal" post is queried.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Ok - I cheked your code and: now I have 7 posts, including 3 sticky in my WP. Thanks to your code, I see only 2 sticky but also 3 normal (so there is 5 at all).

Comment: I know why. How many normal posts are displayed depends on "reading" settings in WP Dashboard. But how to avoid that?

Comment: Sorry, i messed up with the counting. Fixed the code, please try again.

Comment: That's it! Briliant! Tank u! U r awesome! :D

Comment: Hey, I still have a problem with this. When there's no sticky posts I see every posts twice. Only when I create min. one sticky posts everything looks good...

Comment: Updated Code again ;)

Comment: Hi @kuchenundkakao! I have question about your code above :) Of corse it's works, but when I add "sticky" value to the post, I can't see class .sticky in post wrapper div. I need it to style a pin inside when post is sticky :) It this normal?

Comment: Well, that depends in how you echo your posts, as this part is not in my Code i can't tell 

Comment: I use ofc <?php post_class');?>, I see others classes like status-publish format-standard, has-post-thumbnail, but not sticky :) Do you need whole code?